# Select top category from subcategory id

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I want to get CategoryID(1) ; if its subcategory(2) is in content table.

I mean: get categoryid (2) from contenttable; find its parentid(1) in categorytable; and select top category row(categoryid:1)  -
So I couldnt select content's top category row , How can I make this ?

categorytable:

```
CategoryID , ParentID
    1            0
    2            1
```

contenttable:

```
  _id, CategoryID
  ...       2
```

code:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT contenttable.CategoryID, categorytable.CategoryID FROM categorytable 
                    INNER JOIN contenttable 
                    ON categorytable.CategoryID = contenttable.CategoryID
```

Comment: hay can you explain it's simple way

Comment: Your question is not clear. How do you match `CategoryID` in `contenttable` with `ParentID` in `categorytable`?

Comment: At least specify how you want your output to be?

Comment: I want to match `CategoryID-2` in `contenttable` with `CategoryID-1` in `categorytable` which is parentID of CategoryID (contenttable)

Comment: contenttable's categoryID has a parentid in category table. I want to get this row.

Comment: But both values are not matching.

Comment: yes, actually as you see: if parentid is 0 : it is parent category. But I dont want to select all parent categories ( where parentid=0). I want to select only if its subcategory is in contenttable! is it possible ? ( 2 is subcategory of 1; and 2 is in contenttable; so select the 1 that is top category of 2 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT parent.CategoryID
FROM categorytable AS parent
JOIN categorytable AS child ON child.ParentID = parent.CategoryID
JOIN contenttable           ON child.CategoryID = contenttable.CategoryID
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for. But is it possible to `Select DISTINCT contenttable.CategoryID`  Because parent is repeating as child count.

Comment: ok, I think  SELECT `DISTINCT` parent.CategoryID ... is solved problem, thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is still unclear.
Is this query you are looking for?

```
select CategoryID.categorytable from categorytable where CategoryID.categorytable=(select ParentID.categorytable from categorytable where CategoryID.categorytable=(select CategoryID.contenttable from contenttable));
```

Comment: These subqueries are not scalar subqueries.